# Wordpress Fatal Error Call to Undefined Function Theme SNAFU

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I was trying to edit the code of my WP theme that was installed, and I was trying to take things out to disable a function I wanted to get rid of. I was saving the unedited code and everything so I could put it back if needed but I got a Fatal Error. I never realised messing with any of that code could mess with my actual access to my Wordpress dashboard:

```
**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sun_post_lightbox_init() in /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Noiiice/wp-content/themes/sun-by-osetin/functions.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Noiiice/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): sun_setup('')
#1 /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Noiiice/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Noiiice/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Noiiice/wp-settings.php(433): do_action('after_setup_the...')
#4 /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Noiiice/wp-config.php(83): require_once('/homepages/34/d...')
#5 /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Noiiice/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/homepages/34/d...')
#6 /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Noiiice/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/homepages/34/d...')
#7 /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs in /homepages/34/d681692875/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Noiiice/wp-content/themes/sun-by-osetin/functions.php on line 41
```

Comment: copy the functions.php file from the original version. I assume you got it in a zipfile or something

Comment: Ok yeah I found the functions.php and copied it... what's my next move? I can't get back to edit anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not hosting on my own server, so I can't access anything here... I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which kind of hosting you have, you should have access to the site's files by FTP, SFTP, or through the hosting account's web-based file manager. You can use one of those methods to replace the theme's file(s) on the server -- or you can download the copy of that file that you modified, change it to fix the last change you made, and then upload it again.

Theme files are located in `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/`.

If you're not sure which type of access you have or which username/password to use to get to the files, the hosting company should be able to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm gonna try that. I'll let you know how it goes. Really appreciate the help guys.

Comment: Matt, I'm in FileZilla trying to figure out what I need to delete to fix my account, or start over from scratch, does it say what is corrupt or anything somewhere in that fatal error code?

Comment: It says that the `sun_post_lightbox_init()` function is missing, but I don't know where that should be in that particular theme... I'd normally guess it would be in the same functions.php file. I would start by renaming the "sun-by-osetin" directory (found at `wp-content/themes/sun-by-osetin/`), which should disable the theme and prevent the error so you can use the wp-admin again. If you can reinstall the theme after that, it may fix the issue. If that doesn't fix it, you might need to contact the theme author. After it's fixed, remember to delete the old theme directory.

Comment: Perfect I"ll try that! I appreciate your help.